# Implementing a Map where keys are sets of non-overlapping ranges

Tags: java, android, performance

I am facing a performance issue with my current implementation using `List` and loops. I was thinking to make some custom `Map` but is it possible to override the getter properly to work with following setup:

Map contains custom objects and key can be following:

```
case A key: "10"
calling get("10") would return matching object

case B key: "10;12;14"
calling get("10"),get("12"),get("14") would return same object

case C key: "10;20-30"
calling get("10"), get(value between 20 and 30) would return same object
```

Is using a Map in this kind of scenario the best way, what could be the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: You can implement a custom data structure, wrapping a `Map`, instead of override `get` method.

Comment: What if one object has key, say `"10-20"` and another has key  `"15-25"`, what should `get("16")` return?

Comment: That is not possible in my case, the "map" is pre filled on startup from hard coded json file.

Comment: You could use the id as key and make several entries that map to the same object instance.

Comment: @Fildor I thought about that, but if the range is like 1-1000, there would be 1000 entries created instead of 1

Comment: So? About what sizes are we talking here? Is that really likely to happen with many object instances? Can those ranges change during runtime, by the way?

Comment: Could you be looking for a [RangeMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Added full implementation

**UPDATE 2:** If you want you can use [RangeMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) for internal `theMap` as suggested in the comments.

If you key ranges don't overlap, you can create a custom container which internally stores data in `TreeMap` with a custom key which implements `Comparable`:

```
class MyStorage<T> {
    private static final class Range implements Comparable<Range> {
        private int first;
        private int last;

        public Range(int first_, int last_) {
            first = first_;
            last = last_;
        }

        // This heavily relies on that the ranges don't overlap
        @Override public int compareTo(Range other) {
            if (last < other.first)
                return -1;
            if (first > other.last)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private Map<Range, T> theMap = new TreeMap<Range, T>();

    public void put(String key, T obj) {
        String[] ranges = key.split(";");
        for (String range : ranges) {
            //System.out.println("Adding " + range);
            String[] bounds = range.split("-");
            //System.out.println("Bounds " + bounds.length);
            int first = Integer.parseInt(bounds[0]);
            if (bounds.length == 1)
                theMap.put(new Range(first, first), obj);
            else 
                theMap.put(new Range(first, Integer.parseInt(bounds[1])), obj);
        }
    }

    public T get(String key) {
        return get(Integer.parseInt(key));
    }

    public T get(int key) {
        return theMap.get(new Range(key, key));
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        MyStorage<Integer> storage = new MyStorage<Integer>();
        storage.put("10;20-30", 123);
        storage.put("15;31-50", 456);

        System.out.println(storage.get("42"));
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the ranges can be scattered. So, e.g. "keys" 10, 12, 30-40 can identify the same object. Your solution only allows for one range per object, right?

Comment: @Fildor, you are correct. Key can contain individual values combined with range of values

Comment: @Niko Check the implementation I added

Comment: @Fildor no, multiple ranges per object are allowed.

Comment: You'd make one entry per range, but still several entries with same instance. Now I see.

Answer (score 1):

There is a structure called an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) that may fit your needs. Here's an implementation of it.

It allows you to attach objects to intervals rather than the usual object.

Note that this implementation does not implement the sorted indexes suggested by the original algorithm as the use case I needed it for did not require that level of speed.

```
/**
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <T> - The type stored in the tree. Must implement IntervalTree.Interval but beyond that you can do what you like. Probably store that value in there too.
 */
public class IntervalTree<T extends IntervalTree.Interval> {

    // My intervals.
    private final List<T> intervals;
    // My center value. All my intervals contain this center.
    private final long center;
    // My interval range.
    private final long lBound;
    private final long uBound;
    // My left tree. All intervals that end below my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> left;
    // My right tree. All intervals that start above my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> right;

    public IntervalTree(List<T> intervals) {
        if (intervals == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // Initially, my root contains all intervals.
        this.intervals = intervals;

        // Find my center.
        center = findCenter();

        /*
         * Builds lefts out of all intervals that end below my center.
         * Builds rights out of all intervals that start above my center.
         * What remains contains all the intervals that contain my center.
         */
        // Lefts contains all intervals that end below my center point.
        final List<T> lefts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Rights contains all intervals that start above my center point.
        final List<T> rights = new ArrayList<>();

        // Track my bounds while distributing.
        long uB = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long lB = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            long start = i.getStart();
            long end = i.getEnd();
            if (end < center) {
                // It ends below me - move it to my left.
                lefts.add(i);
            } else if (start > center) {
                // It starts above me - move it to my right.
                rights.add(i);
            } else {
                // One of mine.
                lB = Math.min(lB, start);
                uB = Math.max(uB, end);
            }
        }

        // Remove all those not mine.
        intervals.removeAll(lefts);
        intervals.removeAll(rights);
        // Record my bounds.
        uBound = uB;
        lBound = lB;

        // Build the subtrees.
        left = lefts.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(lefts) : null;
        right = rights.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(rights) : null;

        // Build my ascending and descending arrays.
        /**
         * @todo Build my ascending and descending arrays.
         */
    }

    /*
     * Returns a list of all intervals containing the point.
     */
    List<T> query(long point) {
        // Check my range.
        if (point >= lBound) {
            if (point <= uBound) {
                // In my range but remember, there may also be contributors from left or right.
                List<T> found = new ArrayList<>();
                // Gather all intersecting ones.
                // Could be made faster (perhaps) by holding two sorted lists by start and end.
                for (T i : intervals) {
                    if (i.getStart() <= point && point <= i.getEnd()) {
                        found.add(i);
                    }
                }

                // Gather others.
                if (point < center && left != null) {
                    found.addAll(left.query(point));
                }
                if (point > center && right != null) {
                    found.addAll(right.query(point));
                }

                return found;
            } else {
                // To right.
                return right != null ? right.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
            }
        } else {
            // To left.
            return left != null ? left.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
        }

    }

    private long findCenter() {
        //return average();
        return median();
    }

    protected long median() {
        // Choose the median of all centers. Could choose just ends etc or anything.
        long[] points = new long[intervals.size()];
        int x = 0;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            // Take the mid point.
            points[x++] = (i.getStart() + i.getEnd()) / 2;
        }
        Arrays.sort(points);
        return points[points.length / 2];
    }

    /*
     * What an interval looks like.
     */
    public interface Interval {

        public long getStart();

        public long getEnd();

    }

    /*
     * A simple implemementation of an interval.
     */
    public static class SimpleInterval implements Interval {

        private final long start;
        private final long end;

        public SimpleInterval(long start, long end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public long getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        @Override
        public long getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + start + "," + end + "}";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make some test data.
        final int testEntries = 1 * 100;
        ArrayList<SimpleInterval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < testEntries; i++) {
            // Make a random interval.
            long start = random.nextLong();
            intervals.add(new SimpleInterval(start, start + 1000));
        }
        ProcessTimer timer = new ProcessTimer();
        IntervalTree<SimpleInterval> tree = new IntervalTree<>(intervals);
        System.out.println("Took " + timer);
    }

}
```